# How to find the table and column name affected by a stored procedure at runtime?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

Let say I have a stored procedure with if else condition in its logic. Which says if a condition is true then update tableA else update tableB. I wanted to get the table name that got affected with all its columns whose values were updated based on the conditional execution that took place while running the Stored procedure.

This for logging purpose that what table, column got affected by which Stored Procedure and by whom.
I am using SQL server 2008. Please let me know in case you have any suggestions to achieve this.

Comment: Analysing the data from the query execution plan (as SSMS can do) may give you this information. *But*, you might be better off using triggers to record changes if you cannot perform this in the clients (which would be better, avoiding action at a distance).

Comment: Is this a one time task, or something that will be done always?

Comment: @jarlh This would log the details whenever the stored procedure modifies any data in any table in that particular database.

Comment: I can not add triggers as it not allowed by client and its clients database. I thought a Solution to record inserts/updates in a temp table in the stored procedure then return it along with the result set. However, this is pretty bad idea and requires change in Stored Procedure's Logic. This may become messy. So I wanted a simple way though which I can identify the updates done by the Stored Procedure.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of different ways of doing logging but one approach is to use triggers. See [DML Triggers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms178110.aspx) in the SQL Server online docs. Create a log table then create an AFTER TRIGGER on TableA and TableB to write appropriate information to the logging table.

Comment: I can not add triggers as it not allowed by client and its clients database. I thought a Solution to record inserts/updates in a temp table in the stored procedure then return it along with the result set. However, this is pretty bad idea and requires change in Stored Procedure's Logic. This may become messy. So I wanted a simple way though which I can identify the updates done by the Stored Procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Row-Level & Column-Level Tracking

Change Tracking enables an application to keep track of all changes made by the user and this is an inbuilt method

[enter link description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rjath.jpg)

SQL Server Change Tracking determines if a column changed so I decided to give it a try in 2008 R2 using the script below.  Basically in the last update statement I update a column to the same value which already exists in the column.  SQL appears to just record that the column was involved in the update statement.  Unfortunately this means that anyone who desires to perform sync operations at the column level must write more complicated row update logic.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Test]( 
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, 
    [A] [varchar](50) NULL, 
    [B] [int] NULL 
CONSTRAINT [PK_Test] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
( 
    [Id] ASC 
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY] 
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER DATABASE TrackingTest 
SET CHANGE_TRACKING = ON 
(CHANGE_RETENTION = 2 DAYS, AUTO_CLEANUP = ON)

ALTER TABLE TrackingTest.dbo.Test 
ENABLE CHANGE_TRACKING 
WITH (TRACK_COLUMNS_UPDATED = ON);

GO

INSERT INTO dbo.Test (A,B) VALUES ('C', 50) 
INSERT INTO dbo.Test (A,B) VALUES ('D', 50)

SELECT 'SYS_CHANGE_COLUMS = NULL means that all columns changed.' 
SELECT 
    CT.Id, CT.SYS_CHANGE_OPERATION, 
    CT.SYS_CHANGE_COLUMNS, CT.SYS_CHANGE_CONTEXT, 
    CHANGE_TRACKING_IS_COLUMN_IN_MASK (COLUMNPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID('dbo.Test'), 'A', 'ColumnId'),CT.SYS_CHANGE_COLUMNS) AS A_CHANGED, 
    CHANGE_TRACKING_IS_COLUMN_IN_MASK (COLUMNPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID('dbo.Test'), 'B', 'ColumnId'),CT.SYS_CHANGE_COLUMNS) AS B_CHANGED 
FROM 
    CHANGETABLE(CHANGES dbo.Test, NULL) AS CT

DECLARE @synchronization_version BIGINT 
SET @synchronization_version = CHANGE_TRACKING_CURRENT_VERSION();

SELECT * FROM dbo.Test 
SELECT 'Changing both columns via "UPDATE dbo.Test SET A=''E'', B=51"' 
UPDATE dbo.Test SET A='E', B=51 
SELECT * FROM dbo.Test

SELECT 
    CT.Id, CT.SYS_CHANGE_OPERATION, 
    CT.SYS_CHANGE_COLUMNS, CT.SYS_CHANGE_CONTEXT, 
    CHANGE_TRACKING_IS_COLUMN_IN_MASK (COLUMNPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID('dbo.Test'), 'A', 'ColumnId'),CT.SYS_CHANGE_COLUMNS) AS A_CHANGED, 
    CHANGE_TRACKING_IS_COLUMN_IN_MASK (COLUMNPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID('dbo.Test'), 'B', 'ColumnId'),CT.SYS_CHANGE_COLUMNS) AS B_CHANGED 
FROM 
    CHANGETABLE(CHANGES dbo.Test, @synchronization_version) AS CT

SET @synchronization_version = CHANGE_TRACKING_CURRENT_VERSION();

SELECT * FROM dbo.Test 
SELECT 'Only setting column A to the value already in the column via "UPDATE dbo.Test SET A=''E''"' 
UPDATE dbo.Test SET A='E' 
SELECT * FROM dbo.Test

SELECT 'Now SYS_CHANGE_COLUMS has a value showing that only A was changed' 
SELECT 'To bad it isn''t smart enough to know that the data did not change!'

SELECT 
    CT.Id, CT.SYS_CHANGE_OPERATION, 
    CT.SYS_CHANGE_COLUMNS, CT.SYS_CHANGE_CONTEXT, 
    CHANGE_TRACKING_IS_COLUMN_IN_MASK (COLUMNPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID('dbo.Test'), 'A', 'ColumnId'),CT.SYS_CHANGE_COLUMNS) AS A_CHANGED, 
    CHANGE_TRACKING_IS_COLUMN_IN_MASK (COLUMNPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID('dbo.Test'), 'B', 'ColumnId'),CT.SYS_CHANGE_COLUMNS) AS B_CHANGED 
FROM 
    CHANGETABLE(CHANGES dbo.Test, @synchronization_version) AS CT 

Results are:
```

[image]

Comment: I don't have permission to enable the CHANGE_TRACKING on clients DB. Isn't there a programmable approach rather than changing config and settings?

Comment: This topic describes how to enable and disable change tracking for a database and a table.   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb964713.aspx            https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb895205.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You need to create `UPDATE triggers` on `TableA` and `TableB`. Here is following syntax:

```
CREATE TRIGGER TriggerName
    ON [dbo].[TableName]
    FOR UPDATE
    AS
    BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    -- here goes your code
    -- you can select updated values by following
    SELECT *
    FROM
      inserted
    INNER JOIN
      deleted
        ON inserted.PrimaryKey = deleted.PrimaryKey
        -- Update is detected when is in both: deleted and inserted
    END
```

**UPDATE**

So you can select updated data from stored procedure and insert It to temp table.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_example
@var1 INT,
@var2 NVARCHAR(40),
@var3 NVARCHAR(60)
AS
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO ExampleTbl VALUES (@var1, @var2, @var3)
   -- You could create temp table as shown below
   CREATE TABLE #TempTbl
   (
      Id INT,
      Name NVARCHAR(40),
      Email NVARCHAR(60),
   )
   INSERT INTO #TempTbl VALUES (@var1, @var2, @var3)   
   SELECT * FROM #TempTbl
END
```

Comment: I can not add triggers as it not allowed by client and its clients database. I thought a Solution to record inserts/updates in a temp table in the stored procedure then return it along with the result set. However, this is pretty bad idea and requires change in Stored Procedure's Logic. This may become messy. So I wanted a simple way though which I can identify the updates done by the Stored Procedure.

Comment: I updated my answer with simple creation of temp table, inside stored procedure to hold updated values.